# stackrel with dots

Tags: ellipsis

I'd like to insert some symbols over the `\dots`. I'm doing it with `\stackrel` but I guess that it is changing the category of the `\dots` symbol so the space after it is different.

How is the right way to typeset this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$[1,\dots,n]$

$[1,{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}},n]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\overset{\times r}{\dotsc}` instead?

Comment: `$[1,\mathbin{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$`

Comment: @egreg, the output is the same as with `\stackrel`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `\stackrel` under any circumstance: `\overset` does *much* better. In this case we need to help it a bit, however:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$[1,\dots,n]$

$[1,\mathpunct{\overset{\times r}{\dotsc}},n]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: the space after the ellipsis in the first example is regulated by the fact that `\dots` acts as a punctuation symbol. With a simple `\overset{\times r}{\dots}` it wouldn't be considered as such, but just as an ordinary symbol, so we help LaTeX in order to find the correct spacing, because `\overset` doesn't catch all types.

Comment: Nice! It also works with `\dots` instead of `\dotsc`.

Comment: @Sigur Better use `\dotsc`, IMO. I changed the code, because otherwise the `\times r` bit would be shifted too much to the right.

Comment: Sorry, I can not see visual difference between `\dotsc` and`\dots`. Maybe reading the log.

Comment: @Sigur `\dots` uses some rules to decide whether low or centered dots should be used, based on the token that follows it. With no clue it uses low dots. However, the system is set up so that different conventions can be enforced. Thus `amsmath` provides `\dotsc` (pretend a comma follows), `\dotsb` (pretend a binary operation follows, not multiplication), `\dotsm` (pretend a multiplication symbol follows), in order to be sure the correct dots are chosen, according to the publisher's convention.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But you said *`\times r` bit would be shifted too much to the right* and I can not see this. But OK, I agree that it is better to use `\dotsc`.

Comment: @Sigur With `\overset{\times r}{\dotsc{}}` it would, that's why I changed the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, with a correction for  `\times r` to be centred over the dots:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$[1,\dots,n]$

$[1,\stackrel{\times r\;}{\dots{}},n]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution by "trial by error".

Each column portrays the original unstacked `\dots` followed by the `\stackrel`ed `\dots`, subject to `\mathpunct`, `\mathop`, `\mathrel`, `\mathbin`, and `\mathod`, respectively.

The first column is with a trailing `{}`, the second column is with no leading or trailing placeholders, while the third column is with both leading and trailing `{}` placeholders.

[With egreg's help], I found two approaches that work.  Clearly the favored one is `\mathpunct`, as it gives the proper result in all three columns.  In addition, the `$[1,\mathop{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$`, given on the third line of the first column, also matches the initial result.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
{\tiny \verb|\mathxxx{...}{}              \mathxxx{...}               {}\mathxxx{...}{}| \par}

\parbox[t]{1in}{

$[1,\dots,n]$

$[1,\mathpunct{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$

$[1,\mathop{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$

$[1,\mathrel{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$

$[1,\mathbin{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$

$[1,\mathord{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$
}
\parbox[t]{1in}{
$[1,\dots,n]$

$[1,\mathpunct{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}},n]$

$[1,\mathop{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}},n]$

$[1,\mathrel{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}},n]$

$[1,\mathbin{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}},n]$

$[1,\mathord{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}},n]$
}
\parbox[t]{1in}{
$[1,\dots,n]$

$[1,{}\mathpunct{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$

$[1,{}\mathop{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$

$[1,{}\mathrel{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$

$[1,{}\mathbin{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$

$[1,{}\mathord{\stackrel{\times r}{\dots}}{},n]$
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot `\mathpunct`

Comment: I was going to ask the category of punctuation

Comment: @egreg Hah.  I was looking through my TeXbook to see what I missed.

Comment: Nice! Well organized examples.